# Wireshark not showing SNMP

Tags: networking, udp, wireshark, snmp

I am having an issue with wireshark capture. The wireshark doesn't show SNMP protocol but as UDP and complaints as malformed packet.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXcfN.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXcfN.jpg May I know the reason and solution for this issue.

Thanks and Regards,
Alexander.

Comment: It is not uncommon to receive a non-compliant/malformed SNMP packet, so I rather trust Wireshark which is time-tested by the community.

Comment: Some spoof applications sending on port 161? You conveniently don't show the hex packet which any SNMP expert would be able to interpret.

Comment: Please post the entire (include hex) decode in plain text.  The way to do this is a bit complicated but well worth learning.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your packet is cut out in the middle.

Notice that both the IP and the SNMP length field are indicating longer payload than there actually is (they are even marked red for that reason).

Somewhere in the way from the sender to wireshark the packet was cut short. could be because of a malfunctioning router, BER, or just corrupted pcap file.

Wireshark has a really hard time trying to dissect packets (remember it doesn't know the configurations on the end components), but it does it's best with heuristics defined by the community. A malformed packet not being dissected right is not surprising.

If you decide to change WS's heuristics on your PC you may as well do that using [LUA plugins](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua).

Comment: There is no SNMP length field.  BER is unlikely if this result is consistent and the ethernet crc passes.  Why would just 1 field get corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

It is flagged as UDP -vs- SNMP because the destination port is not 161 nor 162.

The length error is self explanatory.

To fix, contact the sender of the packet--probably a bug.